# Splitting fields and isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Please check these statements whether those are true

1. Let $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ be extension fields of $\mathbb{Q}$, the rational numbers.
   Since they are not isomorphic as field hence
   'If $K$ and $E$ have isomorphic Galois group over $F$, then $K$ and $E$ are isomorphic as field' is false.
2. Let $K$, $E$ be splitting fields of polynomial $x^2+3$ , $x^3-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ , respectively.
   Actually, their splitting fields are same. It's $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{3})$.  Therefore,
   'If $K$ and $E$ have same splitting field even if they are splitting fields of different polynomials over same field $F$, then $K$ and $E$ have isomorphic Galois group over $F$' is false.

The reason number 2. is that $E$ has Galois group $\mathbb{Z}_3$ (in fact $E$'s splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ where $\omega$ is a root of $x^2+x+1$ hence automorphism of $E$ depends on value of $\omega$ and it can be $\omega$ or $\omega^2$ or $1$) but $K$ has $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: please use latex to ask your question.

Comment: $x^3 - 1 = (x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ has (only) one root in $\mathbb{Q}$, which is the fixed field of its Galois group.  Its Galois group must then permute the other two roots, so must be $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, not $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: @EricTowers Oh! I made mistake. I thought [Q(w):Q]=3 but it's not true since w^2=-1-w. And then is last sentence of 2. true?